# Visual Studio Code: Breakpoint set but not yet bound - Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, vuex

I have a large Vue.js project which I am trying to get Debugging working properly with in VS Code. I've been trying various different things for a full week now and I keep getting problems with binding breakpoints. For what it's worth, these typically crop up worse in classes that are created through a factory pattern or things like Vuex actions that don't have directly accessible function endpoints - this may be related.

Here's a sample of some launch configs...

```
    {
        "name": "Parity - Chrome",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080/app",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
        "breakOnLoad": true,
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
          "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
          "/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
          "/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
          "/*": "*",
          "/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
        }
    },
    {
      "name": "Parity - Edge",
      "type": "edge",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/app",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "breakOnLoad": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/*": "*",
        "/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
      }
    },
```

I get exactly the same behaviour in Chrome and in Edge (not surprising as they are essentially the same browser these days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon digging through the Sources tab in the browser I found that the source maps are mostly all within the webpack folders for this, hence why they aren't being found (the exception being the *.vue files, hence why they would work fine).

The following configuration works for me, but the full answer is...

**look at where the files are found in 'Sources' in your web browser and
use those locations to map back to the actual file location - doing
what I did before and just trying to use someone else's random config
isn't always going to work.**

```
    {
        "name": "Parity - Chrome",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080/app",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
        "breakOnLoad": true,
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
          "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
          "webpack:///./src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
          "webpack:///./node_modules/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
        }
    },
    {
      "name": "Parity - Edge",
      "type": "edge",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/app",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "breakOnLoad": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "webpack:///./src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "webpack:///./node_modules/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
      }
    },
```